# "Changing sensor privacy requires the following permission: android.permission.MANAGE_SENSOR_PRIVACY" when trying to change sensor_privacy

Tags: adb, permissions, privacy, sensors

I would like to use the following command from ADB

```
service call sensor_privacy 4 i32 1
```

to turn OFF my sensor, but it gives me

```
Changing sensor privacy requires the following permission: android.permission.MANAGE_SENSOR_PRIVACY 
   at com.android.server.SensorPrivacyService$SensorPrivacyServiceImpl.enforceSensorPrivacyPermission(SensorPrivacyService.java:130)
   at com.android.server.SensorPrivacyService$SensorPrivacyServiceImpl.setSensorPrivacy(SensorPrivacyService.java:99)
   at android.hardware.ISensorPrivacyManager$Stub.onTransact(ISensorPrivacyManager.java:135)
   at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
   at android.os.BinderexecTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

Can someone help me? I'm new to this.